# Reflection in Java - ClassCastException

Tags: java, class, object, reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;


class Start
{
  public static void main( String[] argv ) 
  {
      String me, klasa;
      Object arg;
      Method met;

      int v=argv.length-1;
      int argc =argv.length;

      if ( argc == 0 ) {
          System.err.println( "err!!!");
          return;
      }

      try 
      {   while (argc!=0)
      {
          Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[v]);
          klasa = (String) c.newInstance();

          Method[] m = InfoInterface.class.getMethods();

          arg =  m[2].invoke(c.newInstance());
          me = (String) m[1].invoke(c.newInstance());
          klasa = (String) m[0].invoke(c.newInstance());                  

          met = klasa.getClass().getMethod(me, String.class);
          met.invoke(klasa, arg);
          --argc;
      }    

      }
      catch ( Exception e ) { System.out.println(e) ; return; }
    }
}
```

I dont know why in this code shows me ClassCastException. I have searched the error since hour and i have no idea what's wrong with it. Help me please!

The classes to program are add via commend line.

Comment: Sooo, what is the exception message?

Comment: It's hard to say which line gives ClassCastException - you should better provide the stacktrace you get.

Comment: And the input you run this with.

Comment: I think the problem is on the line `klasa = (String) c.newInstance();`. If `c` is not of type `Class<String>` (which I think is the case here) you'll get a ClassCastException.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish with this code? `klasa = (String) c.newInstance();` doesn't make sense, unless you will pass as last argument in your command line `lang.String` but in that case `(String) c.newInstance();` is equivalent of `new String()` so you don't need reflection here at all.

Comment: You are too used to C/C++; you have no need for an argc. Just use a foreach loop on `argv` (which is customarily called `args` in Java anyway)

Comment: Also, there are NO GUARANTEES AT ALL that `.getMethods()` will always return the methods in the way they have been declared. You should really explain more what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely weird. What are you trying to do?

I think, you are trying to cast some Object to String in one of these lines:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(argv[v]);
me = (String) m[1].invoke(c.newInstance());
klasa = (String) m[0].invoke(c.newInstance());
```

Depends on which methods InfoInterface has.